# Comment exprimer le « data center » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, terminologie, informatique

J'écris un texte, un rapport, une thèse, un mémoire, un document d'information, une marche à suivre, une explication, un article, une publicité, un roman, de la poésie, une définition, un curriculum vitae, une loi, un règlement, une étiquette, ou je parle avec mes collègues, et j'ai ce terme à l'esprit, « **data center** », cet « endroit » où sans doute finira par se retrouver toutes ces choses, mais les mots me manquent pour m'exprimer. Si je n'avais pas préféré être né sous une autre bannière que la mienne ou si je n'étais pas obnubilé par l'idée que ce terme de haute voltige sonnât si bien dans sa langue originale et qu'il signifiât quelque chose de très très compliqué dont le sens opaque, inaccessible, était exclusivement réservé aux intimes en génuflexion faisant constamment un voyage intellectuel dans une vallée sablonneuse à l'autre bout du monde, au point de me priver du désir de m'exprimer en français ou de penser qu'elle fût incapable de le représenter, que dirais-je donc plutôt ?

Comment: De la poésie??? Quel ignoble et peu poétique sujet. Je vois déjà d'ici les titres des ces œuvres majestueuses: *Ode à mon cubicule, Élégie de l’archiviste, Le blues de la fonctionnaire, Mélopée de la pause-café...* :D

Comment: @Montéedelait _Ah, comme la donnée a donné... un centre de données_ !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En français on l'embarras du choix selon qu'on décide d'employer un terme qui mettra davantage l'accent sur l'*informatique*, le *traitement* ou les *données* ou qui ressemblera davantage morphologiquement au terme de langue anglaise (des nuances techniques peuvent faire l'objet d'une analyse plus poussée dans le cadre d'une autre réponse) :

> [Centre informatique, centre de traitement de l'information](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=500754)
>   [Centre de traitement informatique, centre de traitement de données,
>   centre de données](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8874188) (voir aussi [ici](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DATA%20CENTER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) et [là](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_de_donn%C3%A9es)).

Answer (score 1):

*Datacenter* est parfois traduit par *centre de données*, mais cette traduction est incorrecte (un centre de données serait un centre de stockage des données). A la rigueur on peut dire un centre de *traitement* des données, mais ce terme est peu usité dans la profession.

#### Qu'est-ce que c'est ?

C'est une salle informatique de grande taille qui héberge de nombreux ordinateurs et leurs périphériques (dispositifs de stockage et de communication). Il n'y a personne sur place, excepté pour les interventions de raccordement, de maintenance et de sécurité. Les systèmes sont programmés, configurés et supervisés (administrés et pilotés) depuis un ou plusieurs autres endroits, souvent depuis un pays à bas coût (Chine, Inde, pays de l'Est).

La caractéristique principale d'un tel ensemble est la disponibilité garantie (qui peut aller de 25 minutes à 30 h de temps de panne annuel cumulé), qui implique des matériels, mais aussi des sources d'électricité et de refroidissement ainsi que des lignes de communications plus ou moins fiables et redondants.

D'autre part, les datacenters sont en grande partie la conséquence de l'externalisation de la production informatique, les entreprises fermant leurs propres salles de production pour,

- soit louer un espace avec les commodités associées (servitudes) chez un hébergeur où elles installent leur matériel,
- soit louer des ressources (temps de calcul, espace de stockage, liaison à distance) chez un fournisseur de services qui est propriétaire des systèmes et en loue l'usage à des clients.

La location d'espace pour hébergement est en voie de disparition, les clients ne désirant plus supporter ni les investissements, ni le renouvellement constant des matériels et logiciels.

#### Variété des appellations selon l'usage

On parle de `centre informatique` pour le grand public, mais dans la profession, quand on ne dit pas datacenter -- le terme étant largement entré dans le langage des entreprises de par le monde, on dit `site de production informatique` ou de `site de secours informatique` selon l'utilisation qu'on en fait. Il y a vingt ans on parlait couramment de `centre d'exploitation`.

Exemples:

- "*Il s’agit donc de mettre en place des systèmes particuliers pour l’intégration de systèmes informatisés sur un site de production informatique*" ([thèse de doctorat](https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-01932903/document), p68)
- "*Au sein d'un site de production informatique de La Poste Grand Public à Nancy...*" ([Offre d'emploi](http://www.sodesys.fr/index-1.html) Chef de Projet - Management de Production Informatique)
- "*Mise à disposition d'un centre de secours informatique. Client : Ministère de l'Education Nationale*" ([appel d'offres](https://www.marchesonline.com/appels-offres/attribution/mise-a-disposition-d-un-centre-de-secours-informatique/am-8185077-1) pour un marché public)

Avec l'évolution des techniques, on parle de plus en plus de `fermes de serveurs`, en particulier avec la production "[dans le nuage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)" qui fait abstraction des machines, de leurs caractéristiques et même de l'endroit où elles sont hébergées.

- "*Google entretient le mystère. Difficile de déterminer précisément les emplacements de ses 'fermes', des centres de serveurs disséminées aux quatre coins du globe*" ([Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/technologies/article/2007/06/14/les-fermes-cachees-de-google-grosses-consommatrices-d-energie_919346_651865.html))

Comment: Je ne comprends pas trop ce qui ne vous plaît pas dans "centre de données". Il n'est pas plus faux ni plus imprécis que les terme anglais! Rien ne dit à première vue (a part l'usage que l'on connait par ailleurs) que datacenter désigne un centre de traitement et non de stockage des données.

Comment: @XouDo: "*Rien ne dit à première vue (a part l'usage que l'on connait par ailleurs) que datacenter désigne un centre de traitement et non de stockage des données*": Les données sont stockées dans ou à proximité immédiate des serveurs qui les utilisent, sinon les traitements seraient considérablement ralentis. L'ensemble forme le "*datacenter*". "Stockage de données" correspond à l'anglais ["*storage area*"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9seau_de_stockage_SAN). Le problème de la traduction mot à mot est le même que si l'on traduit "*big data*" par "grosses données".

Comment: Merci, je sais bien ce qu'est un data center. C'est vous qui indiquez "cette traduction est incorrecte (un centre de données serait un centre de stockage des données)". Bref, je ne vois pas bien en quoi "centre de données" serait incorrect là où data center serait correct.